# Programmatically 'auto hide menubar' in El capitan

Tags: macos, plist, osx-elcapitan

I really love the 'auto hide menubar' option in El Capitan, but sometimes I like it (private) sometimes I don't (work). Is there a way to show/hide it programmatically by changed it's value in a plist file? If so, in which plist file is that setting found? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered by [Rich Trouton on apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209877/programmatically-auto-hide-menubar-in-el-capitan/210088#210088)

Here's how you can set the menubar to be hidden and unhidden using defaults:

To hide:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain _HIHideMenuBar -bool true
```

To show:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain _HIHideMenuBar -bool false
```

Once run, logout and log back in. Alternatively, you can run the following command as the logged-in user to restart Finder and show the changes:

```
killall Finder
```

#### MacOs Sierra

As trevordmiller points out in the comment below, in Sierra it seems you have to close your terminal first to make the change have any effect.

Comment: Any idea how to get this working in Sierra? It seems the _HIHideMenuBar has been renamed or removed as the above isn't working. I've been trying to find a list of all the NSGlobalDomain options for Sierra but haven't had any luck.

Comment: After further testing, I've confirmed that this does indeed work in Sierra, but only after the terminal is closed - `killall Finder` alone isn't enough

Comment: @trevordmiller That's a weird restriction by Apple. I've added your info to the answer for future reference.

Comment: @trevordmiller you've probably learned that the reason you're killing Finder is because the above preference config only applies after an app is restarted. When you restart Terminal it works; when you restart Finder it works; it works if you're okay with restarting every app where you want it to be hidden/showing. Personally, I'm better off with auto-hide and trying to find a way to programmatically activate an item on the menu bar...

Answer (score 5):

As of 10.12.5 I am finding that @trevordmiller is only partially correct; Every application seems to need to be individually restarted to register the new setting. In other words, If I use:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain _HIHideMenuBar -bool false
killall Finder
```

this only shows the menu bar while Finder is active. To show it in other apps, I have to restart them. `Killall Finder` is not required in any way other than that it restarts Finder app and registers the setting for it. Same for restarting any terminal app.

Answer (score 3):

From AppKit release notes:

> NSApplication (New since WWDC Seed)
>
> 10.11 supports a new type of menubar behavior that hides the menubar during normal non-fullscreen interaction. The menubar shows itself
>   automatically when the mouse moves into a hot area at the top of each
>   display. When this mode is enabled, the
>   NSApplication.presentationOptions property will include the
>   NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideMenuBar value.
>
> Prior to 10.11, the SetSystemUIMode API provided by HIToolbox, and the
>   setPresentationOptions API of NSApplication provided by AppKit, did
>   not allow explicitly enabling an auto-hiding menubar without also
>   hiding the Dock. -setPresentationOptions now allows the options to
>   contain AutoHideMenuBar without also including HideDock or
>   AutoHideDock. To ensure compatibility with existing applications, the
>   SetSystemUIMode API will only allow applications linked on 10.11 and
>   later to pass the combination of kUIModeNormal and
>   kUIOptionAutoShowMenuBar; if this combination is specified by an
>   application linked on Yosemite or earlier, the AutoShowMenuBar option
>   is ignored

You are looking for this bit. Flip it as you need.

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, NSApplicationPresentationOptions) {
/* Flags that comprise an application's presentationOptions */
    NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideMenuBar            = (1 <<  2), 
} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_6);
```

Comment: Would definitely work when making apps, but I wanted to achieve this by a terminal command. Sorry, should have provided more details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Too late. If it helps someone else, a shortcut could make it handy.

Open **Automator** -> Select **Service** -> **Service receives selected text** -> Select **no input** in **any application** -> Add **Run Shell Script** action -> Add the following lines.

```
bool=$(defaults read NSGlobalDomain _HIHideMenuBar)
if [ "$bool" == 0 ]; then
    defaults write NSGlobalDomain _HIHideMenuBar -bool true
else
    defaults write NSGlobalDomain _HIHideMenuBar -bool false
fi
```

Save it. (These steps creates a service that runs whenever the system boots.)

To give a shortcut,

Go to **System Preferences** -> **KeyBoard** -> **Shortcuts** -> **Services** -> Scroll to last to find **General** section -> Set a preferred shortcut for the service.

Answer (score 0):

```
❯ /usr/bin/defaults write NSGlobalDomain _HIHideMenuBar -bool [true|false]
```

But you'll have to close instances of the Finder application, and fire it up again:

```
# `-g` don't bring app to foreground, `-a` specify app name
❯ killall Finder && open -ga /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/
```

As a hotkey triggered script to toggle it on/off (hide/unhide):

```
if (( `/usr/bin/defaults read NSGlobalDomain _HIHideMenuBar` == 0 ));
then
    /usr/bin/defaults write NSGlobalDomain _HIHideMenuBar -bool true \
    && killall Finder \
    && open -ga /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/
else
    /usr/bin/defaults write NSGlobalDomain _HIHideMenuBar -bool false \
    && killall Finder \
    && open -ga /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/
fi
```

> - can be used with Alfred workflows, Hammerspoon, Keyboard maestro, Automator, etc.