# Hide menu bar in mac os with a delay

Tags: macos, plist, macos-catalina

In macos it is possible to auto hide the dock, and then set a delay with the line

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float <n>
```

where `<n>` is the number of seconds the mouse has to hover over the dock for it to pop up.

It is also possible to auto hide the menu bar by going to `System Preferences` -> `General` -> `Automatically hide and show the menu bar`.

What I haven't been able to find, and the subject of this post, is how to get the same delay functionality we have for the dock.

As described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014524/programmatically-auto-hide-menubar-in-el-capitan) post, it's possible to hide the menu bar through a terminal with the command

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain _HIHideMenuBar -bool true
```

so I tried the only logical thing I could come up with

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain _HIHideMenuBar-delay -float <n>
```

which doesn't do anything (most likely because the option `_HIHideMenuBar-delay` doesn't exist).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I gave up on it. I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I also am looking for a solution to this. It would be nice even if there was just a way to always hide it, but open it with a shortcut.

Comment: At this point, even an option to completely disable it for full screen apps would suffice.